# UIPageViewController Page Spacing + Background Color

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a couple of UIViewControllers embedded in a UIPageViewController.

Since the bouncing of the UIPageViewController apparently can't be disabled without ugly hacks, I would like to change the color that appears in the background when bouncing. 
I know I can set the backgroundColor with view.backgroundColor, but I would like to have a different color for the background and the little space (Page Spacing) between the VCs.

How can I for example set a blue color for the spacing and a white color for the background that appears when bouncing?

Thank you!